# Updating same table in stored procedure after UPDATE and INSERT

Tags: mysql

**RELATIONSHIP :** `students (1 can have N) addresses`

**SCENARIO:** Students can have many records but only one associated record must have '`current`' field set as '`Yes`' (other value is `NULL`) so the query below should always return only one record per student.

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE student_id = 5 AND current = 'Yes'
```

**PROBLEM:**
People sometimes mark more than one record as 'Yes' after INSERT or UPDATE for same student so I need to avoid it. What is the best way of doing it by using triggers or stored procedures within MySQL?

If UPDATE happens on 'address' table then this should run somewhere to mark other records as NULL: `UPDATE addresses SET current = NULL WHERE student_id = IN_student_id`

If INSERT happens on 'address' table then this should run somewhere to mark other records as NULL: `UPDATE addresses SET current = NULL WHERE student_id = IN_student_id AND id <> IN_inserted_id`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need something updated automatically after data is modified, the right approach is a trigger. Notice a trigger may call a stored procedure.

However you will not be able to implement the described behaviour in a trigger [because](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

In fact, the information "Address X is the current address" should be stored in a column in the `students` table, as a foreign key to the `address` table. Therefore, unicity is guaranteed.

Something like this ([fiddle with it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e66a2d/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  current_address INT,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE address (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  student_id INT NOT NULL,
  contents VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT student_fk FOREIGN KEY student_fk_idx (student_id)
    REFERENCES student(id)  
);

ALTER TABLE student
  ADD CONSTRAINT curraddr_fk_idx
    FOREIGN KEY curraddr_fk_idx (id, current_address)
    REFERENCES address(student_id, id);
```

Notice this structure allows insertion of `students` with no "current address". This is because at least one for the two tables must allow a `NULL` value for their foreign key (or else we cannot add a single row in either table). If it makes more sense, let `address.student_id` be `NULL` instead, and allow an `address` to be nobody's address until you create the corresponding `student`.

Comment: Storing PK of address table as current in students table is a good idea. Thanks